# Using Lombok @Sl4j annoation with log4j implementation

Tags: log4j, slf4j, lombok

I'd like to use the `Lombok` annotation `@Sl4j` in my project, but the default log that `slf4j` uses is `Logback`.

I'd like to set it to use `log4j` implementation.
Is there any way to achieve it?

I saw tutorials online that explain how to achieve it but not while using Lombok annotation.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lombok and Slf4j are separated apis. Your code should use @Slf4j annotation to do logging.

Where it will log is not concern of Lombok but Slf4j configuration. Slf4j manual describes your [desired case](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html). Essentialy your app should use slf4j-log4j12-xxx.jar as backend logger.

So you should setup your app for Log4j logging, log using slf4j annotations and add: slf4j-api.jar, slf4j-log412.jar and log4j.jar in app.

I am assuming that you are using older log4j v1.